# Minimum CakePHP version for PHP 7.3/7.4?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I’m currently on CakePHP 3.5

My ISP is forcing us off PHP 7.2 onto either 7.3 or 7.4

There are some errors from the Cake core code in 7.3, mostly related to compact() (a known breaking change), but I think there are others as well. I’ve seen references to these errors, but I can’t find a definitive version of Cake to target.

What is the minimum CakePHP version needed for PHP 7.3 or PHP 7.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't really matter too much, if you'd upgrade to 3.6 you could as well just upgrade to 3.9 while your at it, besides fixes it's mostly deprecations and new features, and a handful of behavior changes.

That being said, 7.3 has been added to the test runs in [**3.6.13**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/3.6.13), and 7.4 was added in [**3.8.7**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/3.8.7), so the latest 3.6/3.8 would be your minimum.